# A doubt on solvable groups and algebraic Number Theory

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, solvable-groups, ramification

In Marcus book “Number Fields” I have this exercise: (page 124, number 25)
Let $L$ be a normal extension of $K$ and suppose $K$ contains a prime which becomes a power of a prime in $L$. Prove that the Galois group is solvable.

In the preceding exercise I have proved that $D$ and $E$ are solvable groups. If I’m not mistaken quotient of solvable groups is solvable. The the Galois group is isomorphic to the quotient $D/E,$ hence is solvable.
I think there is something wrong in my reasoning, since if I’m right I don’t understand the sense of this exercise...

Comment: What are $D$ and $E$? What is the preceding exercise? Please try to make your question self-contained so that those without a copy of the book can understand it.

Comment: $D,E$ are the decomposition group and the inertia group. I thought this was the standard notation...

Comment: That notation is not standard. As for the exercise, both the inertia and decomposition groups are subgroups of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ and so it can't possibly be the case that the latter is a quotient of the former. Instead, (hint) consider what effect the hypotheses have on the decomposition group...

Comment: The condition means that there is a prime which is totally ramified. Do you know what that means for the inertia group?

Comment: I have made a mistaken. I was convinced that  D/E was isomorphic to the galois group of the extension, while It is actually isomorphic to the galois group of the residue fields extension... I didn't have doubts in the exercise, but a wrong convincement in mind: the galois group is equal to D, which is solvable.